# Objective C and php interaction

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c

hi this waleed i am creating an android application and i want to show the data from mysql to objective C for that i have used the php following is my code

```
+(NSDictionary*) callWebservice : (NSString*)url
{
NSDictionary  *dictionary = nil;
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle(angry)"" message:@"Connection not available." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{

    if (url!=nil && ![url isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"URl : %@",url);
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *resultData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        dictionary = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] objectWithString:resultData error:&error];

        if (dictionary == nil)
        {

            NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSString *resultData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            dictionary = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] objectWithString:resultData error:&error];

        }
    }
}
return dictionary;
```

Now i have call to it in my view controller like this

```
NSLog(@"data is == %@",[Webservice callWebservice:@"http://geekdev786.com/apilive/UserAccount.php?task=GasCompressor&uid=201&page=5"]);
```

it give me the json array in console now i want to save it in the array and show it in the table please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare as a property `NSDictionary` (perhaps `dataForTable`).  And assume the table is called `tableNeedingData`.

In `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`, you'll want something like this...

```
self.dataForTable = [Webservice callWebservice:@"http://oilbaronapp.com/apilive/UserAccount.php?task=GasCompressor&uid=201&page=5"];
// This takes the results of the [Webservice callWebservice:] call and saves it to self.dataForTable

[self.tableNeedingData reloadData];
// This may or may not be necessary depending on when/where you're implementing this
// This just tells the table to refresh itself now that you're certain that self.dataForTable has the data you want to display.
```

Now in your Table DataSource methods, just reach into `self.dataForTable` to get all your information.

For example,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.dataForTable count];
}
```

Comment: one more thing can you tell me how to post ?

Comment: Post what?  If you have questions about how to use a `UITableView`, I suggest you look at other questions on the topic or the official documentation.

Comment: what is datafortable is it nsdictonery ?

Comment: no no not about the tableview

Comment: Yes, in this example, `dataForTable` is an `NSDictionary` property of the object serving as the table's data source.

Comment: i mean right now i am getting data in json array by passing it in query string what if i want to get via post method

Comment: I'd still recommend doing some research on how to use HTTP POST method in Objective-C.  It's an already-answered question on StackOverflow.

Comment: i did but didnt find a good tutorial can you send me the link ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=objective-c+http+post&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: i tried one it returns null